# Why is Maven not recognizing a custom repo for a pom with a parent using Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I have the following parent pom...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
    ...
</project>
```

This installs into a custom artifactory repository. Next I want to consume it so I create a pom like this...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>child</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    ...
    <parent>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.11</version>
    </parent>
</project>
```

All the repository info is stored in the settings.xml. However, when jenkins runs...

```
mvn -f pom.xml --batch-mode help:effective-pom -Drevision=DERIVED -Doutput=effectivePom.xml -s ./build/java/settings.xml
```

It does not use the custom repo and instead uses the default repo. What am I missing? Is there some prestep that needs ran for configuring the repo for parent?

**Settings.xml**

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>CUSTOM</id>
            <username>...</username>
            <password>...</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>CUSTOM-SNAPSHOT</id>
            <username>...</username>
            <password>...</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>mine</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <pluginRepositories>
                ...
            </pluginRepositories>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>CUSTOM-SNAPSHOT</id>
                    <url>...</url>
                    <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>CUSTOM</id>
                    <url>...</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>main</id>
                    <url>...</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <!-- make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>mine</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

I also ran `cat build/java/settings.xml` on the jules job and the file is shown as expected.

**Update 2**

I tried running maven with the -X param to see where things are coming from and it made me notice something...

```
[DEBUG] Using mirror main (...main url) for custom (... custom url).
```

So it looks like somewhere there is a mirror set up incorrectly how do I remove that? I have double checked my code and do not see a mirror anywhere.

Comment: Can you provide the settings.xml that you're using?

Comment: Moreover, is the settings.xml stored in the repository of the pom that you're building? If not, you should use an absolute path for it

Comment: Added and yes it is stored in the project, again this seems to work for other steps (I can deploy on other projects with the same configuration but no parent). I have also used Jenkins scripts to print out that the file location does in fact exist in the Jenkins working directory

Comment: It looks like it should be working. Is there any useful output that I can have a look at?

Comment: No not really besides the fact it isn't trying. I am lost best guess is it is something configured wrong on Jenkins but Other projects have no problem this is the first one with a parent.

Comment: It's a stupid question but, can you check on Artifactory wheter the version of the dependencies and parent are there? I'm asking you because when you use multiple repositories the maven output looks like it is using only one of them (and I guess in your case you're also using the central repo). So maybe the problem is that you're pointing to missing dependencies

Comment: Actually I think I found out what is happening just not why give me a min I will update.

Answer (score 0):

Problem appeared to be a default mirror installed on the Jenkins server (in the settings.xml or whatever it was using). The key was the `-X` option on maven, this showed the mirror mappings. So to resolve this I overrode it to remove the custom repo...

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <!--This sends everything else to /jpmc-public -->
        <id>main</id>
        <mirrorOf>*,!CUSTOM</mirrorOf>
        <url>... main url</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

I only added this to the remote settings.xml, as it would break things locally. However, this seems to have fixed the issue.